# Git rebase cut from

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging, git-rebase

I created a feature branch that was cut from develop.

Another developer cut their feature branch from master.

I want to merge my feature branch into their feature branch but it is not acceptable to take the changes from develop also.

All branches have been pushed.

Essentially i want my branch to have been cut from master and not develop.

How can this be achieved?

My first thought is that maybe some use of rebase but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to discard/ignore all the changes which you have done in your feature branch??

Comment: I would like to keep only my own commits.

Comment: Can you do a simplified drawing ( even if in ascii ) of the branch and which commits you want to remove and which you want to keep, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It is still possible to rebase your branch, even if it has been pushed, changing its starting point from `develop` to `master`. It will however require to force the push if you need to publish it, and other developers will have to redo a fetch or pull.

To do so, checkout `yourbranch`, and do

```
git rebase  --onto master develop
```

You'll then be able to merge both branches, as they have the same starting point the merge will be cleaner, and force push the result. If you don't need to push `yourbranch`, but rather merge it back into `master`, a simple push of the `master` branch will suffice.

Also if you want strict development history it is generally not a best practice to merge two independent feature branches together. If your branch really needs the other's commits, a better alternative is to wait from one of the branches to be merged back to `master`.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** *This solution presumes that you haven't any ***.patch** files in your project root.*

Next commands will extract all commits which are in the **my-feature** branch but not in the **develop** branch into patch files:

```
git checkout my-feature && git format-patch develop
```

Switch to **their-feature** branch and cherry-pick your commits from patches:

```
git checkout their-feature && git am -3 *.patch
```

`-3` parameter is for fallback to 3-way merge if you'll get conflicts.

Comment: Original poster asked about cutting branch from master (instead of from develop) and then apply only his changes, if I understand it correctly.. Any comments?